# "Already tz-aware" error when reading h5 file using pandas, python 3 (but not 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timezone, hdf5

I have an h5 store named `weather.h5`. My default Python environment is 3.5.2. When I try to read this store I get `TypeError: Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert`.

I've tried both `pd.read_hdf('weather.h5','weather_history')` and `pd.io.pytables.HDFStore('weather.h5')['weather_history]`, but I get the error no matter what.

I can open the h5 in a Python 2.7 environment. Is this a bug in Python 3 / pandas?

Comment: Note that I can load the h5 using `weather_store = pd.io.pytables.HDFStore('weather.h5')`, but it's when I attempt to get the table using `weather_store['weather_history']` that the `TypeError` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I'm using Anaconda Python: 3.4.5 and 2.7.3. Both are using pandas 0.18.1.

Here is a reproducible example:

generate.py (to be executed with Python2):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import HDFStore

index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-20 06:00:06.984630-05:00', '2017-06-20 06:03:01.042616-05:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, CST6CDT]', freq=None)
p1 = [0, 1]
p2 = [0, 2]

# Saving any of these dataframes cause issues
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"p1":p1, "p2":p2}, index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"p1":p1, "p2":p2, "i":index})

store = HDFStore("./test_issue.h5")
store['df'] = df1
#store['df'] = df2
store.close()
```

read_issue.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import HDFStore

store = HDFStore("./test_issue.h5", mode="r")
df = store['/df']
store.close()

print(df)
```

Running read_issue.py in Python2 has no issues and produces this output:

> ```
> p1  p2
> ```
>
> 2017-06-20 11:00:06.984630-05:00   0   0
>   2017-06-20 11:03:01.042616-05:00   1   2

But running it in Python3 produces Error with this traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "read_issue.py", line 5, in 
>       df = store['df']
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 417, in **getitem**
>       return self.get(key)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 634, in get
>       return self._read_group(group)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1272, in _read_group
>       return s.read(**kwargs)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2779, in read
>       ax = self.read_index('axis%d' % i)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2367, in read_index
>       _, index = self.read_index_node(getattr(self.group, key))
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2492, in read_index_node
>       _unconvert_index(data, kind, encoding=self.encoding), **kwargs)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 153, in **new**
>       result = DatetimeIndex(data, copy=copy, name=name, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 321, in **new**
>       raise TypeError("Already tz-aware, use tz_convert "
>   TypeError: Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert.
>   Closing remaining open files:./test_issue.h5...done

So, there is an issue with indices. However, if you save df2 in generate.py (datetime as a column, not as an index), then Python3 in read_issue.py produces a different error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "read_issue.py", line 5, in 
>       df = store['/df']
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 417, in **getitem**
>       return self.get(key)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 634, in get
>       return self._read_group(group)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1272, in _read_group
>       return s.read(**kwargs)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2788, in read
>       placement=items.get_indexer(blk_items))
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2518, in make_block
>       return klass(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
>     File "/home/denper/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 90, in **init**
>       len(self.mgr_locs)))
>   ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
>   Closing remaining open files:./test_issue.h5...done

Also, if you execute generate_issue.py in Python3 (saving either df1 or df2), then there is no problem executing read_issue.py in either Python3 or Python2